# How to stop Windows from ever automatically logging off the current user?

Tags: windows-10, kiosk, logoff

I have several MS Surface Pro tablet PCs running Windows 10 Pro that are being used as time clocks. I do not want employees coming to work only to find that the time clock is sitting on a login screen. So the first thing I did set my .NET Windows app as the default shell on boot. I also configured Windows to auto-login without the need to enter a password. I set the PC to never sleep or hibernate. This all works. But yesterday one of the time clocks was sitting on the login screen. Apparently Windows auto-logged out the user.

Now I am trying to figure out how to stop Windows from ever logging off the current user. I started looking in the Event Viewer for clues as to what caused the logout, but there are so many entries and they are not easy to understand.

While I realize that Windows Update may reboot the PC, on reboot the PC will auto-login as I configured it to do.

So, how can I keep Windows from ever logging off the logged in user?

Answer (score 0):

Go to screen saver settings, and uncheck `On resume display logon screen`

Comment: Good idea, except I forgot to mention that I already have the screen saver disabled.

Comment: @JoeGayetty - and I forgot to mention that this doesn't only apply to the screensaver. We had the same problem at my company. The screensaver is turned off from the policy by default, however the login screen appeared often and users had to re enter their passwords. After we unchecked that one checkbox, the problem was gone and only appears when there is a new user created.

Comment: I checked and it is unchecked. But thanks for the information. Good to know.

Comment: @JoeGayetty - does your users have access to the computers? To get to the login screen is as simple as pressing `win + l`

Comment: No, they do not have any access. Input is limited to the time clock application which runs full screen and no keyboard is available. Good idea though. The only explanation that seems possible is that Windows logged off the user somehow.